# Python JSON union dictionay list

Tags: python, json

I've written this code:

```
import json

window_screen = {"window.screen":
                        {"availHeight": 1080,
                       "availLeft": 1920,
                       "availWidth": 1920,
                       "clientHeight": 1080,
                       "colorDepth": 32,
                       "height": 1080,
                       "offsetWidth": 1920,
                       "pixelDepth": 32,
                       "top": 1080,
                       "width": 1920}}

window_navigator = {"window.navigator":
                        {"appVersion": "",
                        "product": "",
                        "vendor": "",
                        "vendorSub": "",
                        "online": "",
                        "appName": "",
                        "appCodeName": "",
                        "oscpu": "",
                        "userAgent": "",
                        "language": "",
                        "languages":"",
                        "platform":""}}

data = dict(window_screen, **window_navigator)

print json.dumps(data, indent=3)
```

The script works, but sorts the lists. I need to print them in the same order as I have written above.

output needed:

```
{
   "window.screen": {
      "availHeight": 1080,
      "availLeft": 1920,
      "availWidth": 1920, 
      "clientHeight": 1080,
      "colorDepth": 32,
      "height": 1080,
      "offsetWidth": 1920,
      "pixelDepth": 32,
      "top": 1080,
      "width": 1920,     
   }, 
   "window.navigator": {
      "appVersion": "",
      "product": "",
      "vendor": "",
      "vendorSub": "", 
      "online": ""
      "appName": "",
      "appCodeName": "",
      "oscpu": "", 
      "userAgent": "", 
      "language": "", 
      "languages": "", 
      "platform": ""

   }
}
```

I need this output, without the properties sorted, how can make this?

Comment: Can you speak English? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python dictionaries do not maintain order, so you cannot guarantee the order you entered the data is the same order it will be in when emitted from `json.dumps()`. If you need an ordered dictionary, check out [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: print OrderedDict(data.items())
same problem :((
i need is same order im writed the code